# How to save an iTunes Podcast to a USB stick?

Tags: itunes, podcasts, quicktime

I have downloaded WWDC 2010 podcast from iTunes. How can I find the Podcast file and save it to a USB Memory stick so people who doesn't have iTunes can play it using quicktime?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Right-Click on the file in iTunes, then select "Show in Finder"

There you have your Podcast-File. You can copy it on your USB-Drive or wherever you want!

Comment: In my memory an alt-drag also did the trick, but it seems not to work anymore.

Comment: What is the source for the quoted first paragraph?

Answer (score 1):

You can:

1. Go into podcasts in iTunes.
2. Select "Show Feed" at the bottom if you haven't already to show episodes not yet downloaded
3. Click the Cloud Icon With Down Arrow next to the episode you want to download
4. Open USB Stick in Finder
5. Drag and drop the downloaded episode from iTunes to USB folder (no need to find the file, this creates a copy on USB stick)